# Iterating over a complex element in XML based on attributes using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML data as shown below

**Input XML**

```
                <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
                <Root>
                    <Child ID = "1">
                        <condition>true</condition>
                        <code>Error-1</code>
                    </Child>
                    <Child ID = "2">
                        <condition>false</condition>
                        <code>Error-2</code>
                    </Child>
                    <Child ID = "3">
                        <condition>true</condition>
                        <code>Error-3</code>
                    </Child>
                    <Child ID = "4">
                        <condition>false</condition>
                        <code>Error-4</code>
                    </Child>
                    <Child ID = "5">
                        <condition>true</condition>
                        <code>Error-5</code>
                    </Child>
                    <Child ID = "6">
                        <condition>true</conditions>
                        <code>Error-6</code>
                    </Child>
                    <Child ID = "7">
                        <condition>false</condition>
                        <code>Error-7</code>
                    </Child>
                </Root>
```

My requirement is to iterate over the conditions element under all the child nodes.

If the **condition** element's value is **true** then I have to fetch the relevant value in the **code** element

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <code>Error-1</code>
    <code>Error-3</code>
    <code>Error-5</code>
    <code>Error-6</code>
```

I have been trying to do this based on attribute **ID** of the Child node. When iterating over the conditions element how to get the attribute **ID** of it's parent node(i.e the Child element) and retain it to fetch the relevant code if the value is true for condition element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Child">
        <xsl:if test="condition[.='true']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="code"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the context of the XSLT you are using I can say that you can accomplish this pretty easily with the right XPath.

```
Root/Child[condition='true']/code
```

You can adjust the context to whatever you need as long as you use the correct predicate.

Comment: I'll be evaluating the condition dynamically so applying filter is not feasible. I have to iterate on the nodes and fetch the code based on the evaluation of conditions. Lets just say that the Condition element holds the value "A=A". I'll be evaluating this using Evaluate() function. If the evaluation succeeds, I have to fetch the relevant code. How can we achieve this in XSLT?

Comment: @Guru Can you update your question with the XSLT you are trying to use? What evaluate function? Also, your question doesn't say anything about an "A=A" condition. This XPath will work and can be modified in a number of different ways depending on what you need it to do.